# Pass model formula as argument in R

Tags: r, function, arguments, cross-validation

I need to cross-validate several glmer models on the same data so I've made a function to do this (I'm not interested in preexisting functions for doing this). I want to pass an arbitrary glmer model to my function as the only argument. Sadly, I can't figure out how to do this, and the interwebz won't tell me.

Ideally, I would like to do something like:

```
model = glmer(y ~ x + (1|z), data = train_folds, family = "binomial"
model2 = glmer(y ~ x2 + (1|z), data = train_folds, family = "binomial"
```

And then call `cross_validation_function(model)` and `cross_validation_function(model2)`. The training data within the function is called train_fold.

However, I suspect I need to pass the model formula in different way using `reformulate`.

Here is an example of my function. The project is about predicting autism(ASD) from behavioral features. The data variable is `da`.

```
library(pacman)
p_load(tidyverse, stringr, lmerTest, MuMIn, psych, corrgram, ModelMetrics, 
caret, boot)

cross_validation_function <- function(model){ 

  #creating folds  
  participants = unique(da$participant)
  folds <- createFolds(participants, 10)


  cross_val <- sapply(seq_along(folds), function(x) {

    train_folds = filter(da, !(as.numeric(participant) %in% folds[[x]]))
    predict_fold = filter(da, as.numeric(participant) %in% folds[[x]])

    #model to be tested should be passed as an argument here    
    train_model <-  model



    predict_fold <- predict_fold %>% 
      mutate(predictions_perc = predict(train_model, predict_fold, allow.new.levels = T),
             predictions_perc = inv.logit(predictions_perc),
             predictions = ifelse(predictions_perc > 0.5, "ASD","control"))

    conf_mat <- caret::confusionMatrix(data = predict_fold$predictions, reference = predict_fold$diagnosis, positive = "ASD") 

    accuracy <- conf_mat$overall[1]
    sensitivity <- conf_mat$byClass[1]
    specificity <- conf_mat$byClass[2]


    fixed_ef <- fixef(train_model) 

    output <- c(accuracy, sensitivity, specificity, fixed_ef)

    })

    cross_df <- t(cross_val)
    return(cross_df)
  }
```

Solution developed from the comment: Using `as.formula` strings can be converted into a formula which can passed as arguments to my function in the following way:

```
cross_validation_function <- function(model_formula){
...
train_model <- glmer(model_formula, data = da, family = "binomial") 
...}

formula <- as.formula( "y~ x + (1|z"))
cross_validation_function(formula)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aim is to extract the model formula from a fitted model, the you can use
`attributes(model)$call[[2]]`. Then you can use this formula when fitting model with the cv folds.

```
   mod_formula <-  attributes(model)$call[[2]]
   train_model = glmer(mod_formula , data = train_data, 
                family = "binomial")
```

Comment: I've developed a solution that doesn't need to fit a model first using `as.formula`. I've added it to the bottom of the orginal post.

Comment: how about `formula(model)` ... ??

Comment: @WiggyStardust like I said before, I thought you wanted to *to extract the model formula from a fitted model*.  I does make better sense to pass the formula as you do now.